# Linux device model: Same device but different drivers

Tags: arm, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux, atmel

I'm customising Linux for an ARM9 Atmel AT91SAM960 board.

In the [device file](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/arm/mach-at91/at91sam9260_devices.c#L901) Atmel named all the USART the same `atmel_usart`. Of course with id enumeration:

```
static struct platform_device at91sam9260_uart0_device = {
        .name           = "atmel_usart",
        .id             = 1,
        .dev            = { ...}
}
```

According to the Linux Device model, all these devices (5 UARTS on a SAM9260) would be bind to [the driver named `atmel_usart`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/serial/atmel_serial.c#L1638).

I don't want to set a TTYS driver on all UARTS which will be registerd. I have several own drivers which serve for different specialised purposes (LON, RS-485 etc.) I want the control which driver does serve a certain USART. So what could I do:

- The Atmel device files are unsatisfiable and I can do it better. So I rename (patch) the devices in the device file. However, in case I want a TTYS driver on UART4 I would be in trouble.
- I manipulate (patch) the device file,
  so that I'm able the access the
  structures `platform_device`. I could
  change their names before I would
  register them. But as far as I
  understood the idea of the *Linux Driver Model*,
  devices should be
  registered early during boot-up but the binding to a driver follows .... later.
- I could write a driver, which has an
  alias name and which would be binded
  to a specific bus_Id ->
  `atmel_usart.4`. Can I really?

What solutions else exist. I want to touch a minimal set of Kernel files but *I want all the freedom possible?*

**Addendum what freedom means to me**: I can specify at runtime how the UARTS can be used

- with the Atmel-Serial driver (ttyS)
- with my own drivers

It means also, that changes to the kernel source are minimal.

Comment: Clarify on what you want to achieve using these changes (all the freedom possible)..Also how many devices would be connected at a time and will the port gets dynamically changed every time you connect the device, like, first time it gets connected to say, uart2 device, next time it would get connected to uart4 device?

Comment: As it is an embedded device with specific hardware wired to the UARTS, there want be many dynamic changes. The connections are as follow: UART0=Serial Console | UART1=Expansion to other Hardware | UART1=TTYS-Interface to a Bus-System (LON) | UART3=OwnDriver-Interface to a Bus-System (X). But keep in mind how dynamic it can get if Serial-USB devices are used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I built my own line discipline drivers. You can build them as kernel modules and attach them to the UARTs at runtime. No changes to the Linux source are necessary.

Any funny timing or control stuff can be done through ioctl(). Specifically, I implemented a timing-sensitive RS-485 protocol in this way.

When I did this (Linux 2.6.17) there was no dynamic registration mechanism, so I overwrote the existing line disciplines. The Linux code is (was) pretty straightforward, and I was satisfied that this would be a safe thing to do.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is quite easily solved.  The 5 UART devices are presently registered at kernel startup and their function is locked.  This is now how it normally works for PCI or USB devices, right?  So what you need to do is pull the device registration out of the startup code and register it dynamically.  You can even register/unregister as needed.

at91_register_uart() is being called from your board file for every UART that needs registered.  at91_add_device_serial() will then platform_device_register all those you what setup.  One solution is to let at91_register_uart() be called for all 5 UARTS, but then remove the call to at91_add_device_serial() from your board.  You can then make it an exported function that can be called by your loadable drivers.  You can even add an argument to it (int) so that instead of looping on all UARTS, you can select which ones to register individually.  You can also mirror this function by making one that unregisters the devices.

NOTE:  I think you'll need to always leave one UART dedicated as your console, if you are using one that way.  You could probably hide that in the exported function by only allowing index 0->3 as in input and then mapping 0->3 to 0-4, skipping the UART that you want to use for console.